# DataGridView takes a long time to update using OracleDataAccess.Fill(datatable)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my application also have a function that executes an oracle function and brings the data. But when this return is large, it takes 20 to 40 seconds to process and populate the table in every refresh until the amount of data decreases. These table have about 12 columns and the problem appears when process over 50~60 rows.

The query in oracle is quite simple and does not show such slowness.
Is there any alternative to this or any way to optimize this process? I update the table as the application consumes the data one at a time in the first position.

Get Function:

```
        public DataTable GetWorkList(int ordenamiento)
        {
            DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();            

            OracleConnection oraConn = new 
            OracleConnection(this.mesParameters.DBConnectionString);
            OracleCommand oraComm = new OracleCommand();
            OracleDataAdapter oraDA = new OracleDataAdapter();
            OracleParameter oraParam;
            OracleParameter oraParamReturn;

            //Logger.Info("Procedure GETWORKLIST BEGIN");

            try
            {
                oraComm.Connection = oraConn;
                oraComm.BindByName = true;
                oraComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                                

                oraComm.CommandText = "PG_SL_IPR_WORKLIST_RF3";

                oraParam = new OracleParameter("PR_ORDER", OracleDbType.Int32, ordenamiento, ParameterDirection.Input);
                oraComm.Parameters.Add(oraParam);

                oraParamReturn = new OracleParameter("RETURN", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
                oraComm.Parameters.Add(oraParamReturn);

                
                oraConn.Open();
                //Logger.Info("conexão aberta");
                //Logger.Info("oraDA Select BEGIN");
                oraDA.SelectCommand = oraComm;
                //Logger.Info("oraDA Select END");

                //Logger.Info("FILL BEGIN");
                oraDA.Fill(dtTemp);
                //Logger.Info("FILL END");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.mesMessages.OKButtonMessage("GetWorkList\r\n" + ex.Message, "MES", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                if(oraConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    oraConn.Close();
                    //Logger.Info("conexão fechada");
                }
            }
            //Logger.Info("Procedure GETWORKLIST END");
            return dtTemp;
        }
```

SetDataGridView

```
public void SetDataGridView(Parameters prParameters, DataTable prTableInfo, String prTableConfigName)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn dgvColumn;
            String[] strConfigColumnValues;

            try
            {
                this.Columns.Clear();

                for (Int16 i = 0; i < prTableInfo.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Get the config values for each column in order according the query
                    strConfigColumnValues = prParameters.GetParameter(prTableConfigName, prTableInfo.Columns[i].ColumnName.Trim().Replace(' ', '_').ToUpper()).Split('-');

                    dgvColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

                    dgvColumn.DataPropertyName = prTableInfo.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    dgvColumn.Name = prTableInfo.Columns[i].ColumnName.Trim().Replace(' ', '_').ToUpper();
                    dgvColumn.HeaderText = strConfigColumnValues[0].Trim();
                    dgvColumn.Width = Convert.ToInt32(strConfigColumnValues[1].Trim());
                    dgvColumn.ReadOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(strConfigColumnValues[2].Trim());
                    dgvColumn.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(strConfigColumnValues[3].Trim());

                    dgvColumn.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False;
                    dgvColumn.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

                    this.Columns.Add(dgvColumn);
                }

                this.DataSource = prTableInfo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                message.OKButtonMessage(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Profile your code to find which part is the long consuming process.  Also not clear how often you are calling this code.

Comment: Actually one or two well-placed breakpoints may be enough to find the show stoppers

Comment: the frequency that i'm calling this code is something like every 30 seconds when the machine starts to produce. The long consuming process is in SetDatagridView, i added logs to the application an it returns me that is in this function to add the data. You know one good free profiler?

Comment: Do you see any exceptions thrown in the output window? Do you have a handler for the [DataGridView.DataError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) event?

Comment: I don't have a handler for this type of exception. the application should work even if there's exceptions ocurring? and @JohnG yes! the columns dont change, makes sense. but how to do it?

Comment: You can profile things with a StopWatch.  Setting a DataSource for the grid should give you columns, so it's not clear why you add the columns and then set the DataSource.  You can set the DataSource and then change the column properties.  How long does `prParameters.GetParameter(...)` take to run?

Comment: @GustavoMorilla throwing exceptions (even if they will be ignored) could cause a really bad delay. But you should check the output window in VS, make sure the exception messages are shown or simply select all CLR exceptions from the Debug menu/ Exception settings. Just to make sure exceptions are not involved.

Comment: Question… have you wired up the grids `DataError` event? And if so, can you show what it looks like? As others have noted, even with 12 columns and 100 rows of data, this should still only take a second or two to display.

Comment: @LarsTech the GetParmeter doesnt show slowness, only access one config.txt file that have info about the colums. the way that is working now is configure and populate column by column, right?

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply… if the columns do not change, then, add the columns “outside” the method and remove the line… `this.Columns.Clear();` along with the code that re-builds the columns. You should only have to change the grids data source. Changing the data source will automatically remove the existing rows.

Comment: Are you testing this when you have over 50 rows (when you say it's slow)?  Reading a text file is one of the slowest things you can do.

Comment: Read the data from the text file once in the beginning and store it in a list or dictionary (don't know what your text file looks like), then reference the information when you need it.

Comment: We assumed that `SetDataGridView` is the slow part but which portion of it? The Loop or the setting of the datasource. Put one breakpoint on the `for` and one on the `this.DataSource = prTableInfo;`, then run andobserve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the delay was on one HUGE select on Oracle Database, this query finish iaround 4 ~ 7 seconds and it's the root cause of the delay. I did a "Tunning" on that and now everything is ok!